# Unable to remove space between two Horizontal Scroll views in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to create two horizontal scrollable list of elements. Currently, this is what I am able to achieve:

[image]

As can be seen, I want to remove the space between the two Scroll Views. Here, is the code I am using to achieve this:

```
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack (spacing: 0){
                Text("Zara") .font(.custom(
                    "AmericanTypewriter",
                    fixedSize: 36))
                
                ScrollView (.horizontal){
                  
                    HorizontalScrollModel(searchResult: searchResults1)
                
                    
                    
                    
                }.task {
                    await loadData()
                }
                
              
                
                ScrollView (.horizontal){
                  
                    HorizontalScrollModel(searchResult: searchResults1)
                
                    
                    
                    
                }
                
            }
}
}
```

`HorizontalScrollModel()` returns a `LazyHGrid` of the products. I have tried setting the spacing to 0 with `VStack (spacing: 0)` but this did not work. How do I remove the space between the ScrollViews?

`HorizontalScrollModel`:

```
struct HorizontalScrollModel: View {
    

    var searchResults1: [homeResult]
    let columns  = [
        GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 200))]
    
    @State private var isHearted = false


    
    init( searchResult: [homeResult]) {
        self.searchResults1 = searchResult
    
    }
    
    
    
    var body: some View {
        LazyHGrid (rows: columns ){

            ForEach(searchResults1, id: \.prodlink) { item in
                
                NavigationLink{
                    ProductView(imageLink: item.image_src, productLink: item.prodlink ,
                                productCost: String(item.price))
                } label: {
                    VStack (alignment: .leading, spacing: 0){
               
                        AsyncImage(url: URL(string: item.image_src)) { phase in
                            if let image = phase.image {
                                image
                                    .resizable()
                                    .scaledToFit()
                                    .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
                                
                            } else if phase.error != nil {
                                Text("There was an error loading the image.")
                            } else {
                                ProgressView()
                            }
                        }
                        .padding()
                                .overlay(
                                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                                        .stroke(.gray.opacity(0.2), lineWidth: 4)
                                )
                                .padding(.top, 2)
                                .padding(.bottom, 2)

                                .padding(.leading, 2)

                                .padding(.trailing, 2)

                                .overlay (
                                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12)
                                        .stroke(.gray.opacity(0.3), lineWidth: 1))


                            
                    

                    }
               
              


                }


            }
//                    .padding([.horizontal, .bottom])
            

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What’s inside the search results? Could you show how that is structured? Also, perhaps put a background colour on them as it might be that causing the odd spacing.

Comment: Actually. It’s the VStack. The VStack has expanded its contents to fit th screen. If you put a spacer on the end it might work.

Comment: @Fogmeister I have added an image with background colour and it seems to be HorizontalScrollModel() that causes the spacing problem. I have also added the code for the same. I tried putting a spacer but that did not change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `ScrollView` takes all available space offered by `VStack`, which since it has 2 views will be half the screen for each view.

Inside each `ScrollView` you then place a `LazyHGrid`, and inside the cell you are placing a 150x150 image, but the `ScrollView` size will not change to fit the image.

So, it now depends on what you're aiming for. If you just want the two `ScrollView` to be joined together, you can have a `.frame` modified to the outer `VStack` with a height of 308 (150 for each image + the padding).

Comment: That does work. Is there anything more "elegant" then setting the size of the VStack?

Comment: It really depends on what your goal is. I would personally wrap the whole `VStack` in a `GeometryReader`, delete the `.frame` modifier from all the images, and set the `.frame` of the `VStack` to be of size that is relative to the screen. That way I would know the relative size of the `ScrollView` and will still get  more rows from the grid on bigger screens

Answer (score -1):

Try adding the `.fixedSize()` modifier to the `ScrollView`:

```swift
ScrollView(.horizontal) {
    HorizontalScrollModel(searchResult: searchResults1)
}
.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
```

You might also be able to add it just to the `HorizontalScrollModel`.

Comment: I have tried the solution and it does not seem to be working. Please see the edit for added context.